# Are VIXW options PM-settled like SPXW?

Tags: options, vix

Cboe explicitly defines the difference between the options on SPX as AM-settlement and SPXW as PM-settlement, but for VIX and VIXW, they say they're both AM-settled.

I can see in my trading platform that VIXW options expiring today are still actively traded. Why is that? How can an AM-settled option continue to trade the day of expiration? Unless it's PM-settled and I missed fine-print somewhere?